# Submitting form through Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My issue is simple -

I am submitting form using jquery and ajax . When the button is clicked the data is submitted to database .

Question - If the user clicks the submit twice there are two entries in the database . how can I solve this ?

I cannot use .one() because the submit button invokes validation function if the errors happen the data will not be submitted .So , user has to call the same function again .

Obviously I can do that with a variable on .success .but what is the best solution to this issue .

Thanks for the help.

Comment: disable the button with JS, until you receive the response and pop up the response !

Comment: Add overlay element which draw on top of your DOM then user can't interact with your elements, once ajax complete remove the overlay

Comment: and add a UNIQUE constraint if you want in db. Also using session and tokens

Answer (score 1):

Overlaying to prevent click is one way.

If you want something plug and play blockUI.js is good. All you need is

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

or you can just use `.ajaxstart()` and `.ajaxstop(`) to overlay an element yourself to enable and disable the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `submit` button once you have submitted the form. Any form can be submitted only using the `Submit` button. So:

```
$(form).submit(function () {
  $(this).find("input:submit").prop("disabled", true);
  // You can enable it back once the AJAX request is successful.
  $.ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $(form).find("input:submit").prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```